# How to parse unescaped json received as input by lambda function?

Tags: java, json, parsing, aws-lambda, escaping

I'm extracting data using a web scraping tool (Parsehub). After the extraction is done, Parsehub is sending information about this data (in JSON format) to Amazon Lambda, which I'm using as a webhook. But this JSON is not correctly escaped, and hence Lambda is throwing an error (saying, could not parse request body). How do I escape the JSON string so that Lambda doesn't throw an error? I've also tested this functionality using eclipse.

I have used simple java types as input (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html). I have also tried using POJOs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-pojo.html) and byte stream implementation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html) as input, but it's still throwing json parsing error.

This is a part of my Lambda Handler Code :

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        System.out.println("input - " + input);
        return "response";
    }
}
```

This is the JSON, Parsehub is sending to Lambda :

```
{
    "run_token": "I have removed this",
    "status": "complete",
    "md5sum": "90dc9753513a248502414e8d5345a6de /phfiles/ty6qie7-ut5C.gz ",
    "custom_proxies": "",
    "data_ready": 1,
    "template_pages": {},
    "start_time": "2019-01-30T11:01:58",
    "owner_email": "I have removed this",
    "webhook": "https://api endpoint of lambda function",
    "is_empty": false,
    "project_token": "I have removed this",
    "end_time": "2019-01-30T11:02:19",
    "start_running_time": "2019-01-30T11:01:59",
    "options_json": "{"recoveryRules": "{}", "rotateIPs": false, "sendEmail": true, "allowPerfectSimulation": false, "ignoreDisabledElements": true, "webhook": "https://api endpoint of lambda function", "outputType": "csv", "customProxies": "", "preserveOrder": false, "startTemplate": "main_template", "allowReselection": false, "proxyDisableAdblock": false, "proxyCustomRotationHybrid": false, "maxWorkers": "0", "loadJs": true, "startUrl": "https://address of the website from which data is extracted", "startValue": "{}", "maxPages": "0", "proxyAllowInsecure": false}",
    "start_value": "{}",
    "start_template": "main_template",
    "pages": 2,
    "start_url": "https://address of the website from which data is extracted"
}
```

This is the output in my Cloudwatch logs :

```
Lambda invocation failed with status: 400. Lambda request id: eecd695e-61e7-47d9-bc27-04628c99e158
Execution failed: Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 'run_token': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: [B@36f6b2e9; line: 1, column: 11]
```

This is the output in my eclipse console:

```
Invoking function...
==================== INVOCATION ERROR ====================
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvalidRequestContentException: Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character ('r' (code 114)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
at [Source: [B@1ade7b2b; line: 15, column: 21] (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestContentException; Request ID: b46bf0b4-4bb2-4bc0-aa13-81457349153c)
```

As we can see that the **"options_json": "{"recoveryRules": "{}",**....... part of the JSON is not escaped. It's not possible to change the json sent by parsehub. The only data manipulation I can do is on Lambda.

Comment: If it is always the `"options_json"` that is invalid, you can try to transform it with some simple string manipulation.

Comment: But how do I transform it. Inside the handleRequest function right? But the execution doesn't even go inside the function. It throws an error before itself

Comment: I know nothing about Amazon lambdas. But can you try to send the request a Text instead of Json so that it will not parse it ?

Comment: I cannot change the request. Parsehub is sending it.

Comment: That I understand. But when you receive it, can you change it ? Can you tell Lambdas to not parse it or that it is plain text or binary (so that it will not be parsed) and then "patch" it before parsing ?

Comment: That is what my question is. How do i "patch" it?

Comment: *"Amazon Lambda, which I'm using as a webhook"* ...with API Gateway?  If true, I would suggest that your integration request body mapping template could be responsible for transforming the request body incorrectly.  I'd like to think that a service would not be sending such blatantly invalid content.  Check the API Gateway logs, looking for the request body before transformation.

Comment: Yes with API Gateway. And I have already tried this both, with and without the mapping template. It's still not working (throwing the same error). Also, how do I display the request body in the Gateway logs? I know where the logs are, how do I print the request body? @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: I'll have to go back and look... I was thinking it was automatically included in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late to the party. But I had this problem and my conclusions are:

- The API gateway can manage two different protocols. They call them REST and HTTP
- The HTTP protocol has 'routes'. Each route has an integration method with a payload format version
- When designing a webhook in the most easy way, everything is mostly opinionated, so you have a seamless integration between the API Gateway and the lambda with a default catch-all route and  payload format v2.0

This causes that ALL the request goes directly to the lambda event as a big JSON object. Headers, requestContext, body... **The body is not deserialized**, it's just the payload of the 'body' property of this big JSON in an escaped string format.

So, when arriving to the lambda function you have to treat it accordingly to deserialize it and get an object. In case of a Node.js lambda you should do something like

```
exports.handler = async (bigEvent, context) => {
    // Deserializing just the body
    event = JSON.parse(bigEvent.body);
    console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
    return event.key1; 
};
```

For the shake of clarification, I'll say that the bigEvent is something like

```
{
  version: '2.0',
  routeKey: 'POST /endpoint',
  rawPath: '/endpoint',
  rawQueryString: '',
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*',
    ...
  },
  requestContext: {
    accountId: '123456789012',
    ....
  },
  body: '{\n    "key1": "importantDatum",\n    "key2": "..."\n}',
  isBase64Encoded: false
}
```

If you'd want to response with a JSON, you should serialize it before sending (with `JSON.stringify(...)`)